# Export spatial data from SQL Server to ESRI shapefile using OSGeo

Tags: shapefile, sql, spatial-database, osgeo4w

i did a join between 2 tables **departements2** which has all department with their id and geometry with **BM_REGIONFR** with id of department and region ( i have 5 region in each region many departement )

```
 select b.[Region],geometry::UnionAggregate(geom.MakeValid()) AS Geo
 into dbo.DRShape from [dbo].[departements2] a 
 join [dbo].[BM_REGIONFR] b on a.[code_insee] = b.[dep_2] group by b.Region
```

After that i wanted to export the shapefile with OSGeo4w in order to have the map with the right decomposition and thats the query i used

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "C:\Users\sqlexport.shp" "MSSQL:server=PORT_7FMW8H2;database=testdbspatial;trusted_connection=yes;" -sql "select * from DRShape" -overwrite
```

And i got these ERRORS

> ERROR 1: Attempt to write non-polygon (LINESTRING) geometry to POLYGON
>   type shapefile. ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 1 from layer
>   dbo.DRShape. ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed

Answer (score 1):

You're somehow ending up with different types of geometry inside that table. Run this to determine what types are in your table:

> select distinct(geom.STGeometryType()) from DRShape

If you have something called a GeometryCollection you're probably creating it when you do your merge(but not necessarily). A GeometryCollection is valid in SQL but not in a shapefile and mixes geometry types within a single row. If you have these they will need to be exploded into individual parts before you can make your shape file.

If you only have Polygons or Linestrings(anything not a GeometryCollection) returned by the above query you just need to add a where clause to your sql query. (and possibly export two shapefiles if you need both datatypes). Your sql query should look like this:

> -sql "select * from DRShape where geom.STGeometryType() = 'Polygon'"